# my webpage not hosted in localhost firebase web 404 error

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

**at the first picture i have initialized firebase in the program**

**at the second picture i moved the webpage to be hosted in the public directory**
i was asked to delete the index.html page in the tutorial but even i didn't delete it the output was not something i expected 
**at the third picture successfully local hosted the project**

**the fourth picture is the output i got**

> it only displays 404.html and not displaying my web pages to be hosted

[image: here i have initialized firebase]

[image: here i moved the webpages to be hosted into public directory]

[image: successfully local hosted]

[image: it displays only the 404 error page not my hosted webpapge]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code and text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself, so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting 404 because there's no `index.html`.

Try visiting `https://localhost:5000/project3.html`.

If you don't wish to rename your files properly, you can [configure redirects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects).